# Applying a CSS animation from input:checked that transition works the same way checked and unchecked

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do some animation in a div with css rotate() but apparently it only works when I check the label, when I check again just show standard display.

Will be a bonus if someone help me to position the div that I use #rotator before, after vertical, this way they show 45º to a div.

**Example:** https://codepen.io/rafaart/pen/dyNjgeb

```css
    .ativar-dark{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
}

#sky {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rotator {
  position: relative;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  transform: rotate(-45);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 3rem;

}

label{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rotator:before, #rotator:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: inherit;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

#rotator:before {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: -.25rem;
  left: -.25rem;
}

#rotator:after {
  background-color: White;
  bottom: -.25rem;
  right: -.25rem;
}
.ativar-dark:checked ~ .container div{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all ease 2s;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ativar-dark" class="ativar-dark">
<div class="container" id="sky">
  <label for="ativar-dark"> 
  <div id="rotator">
    
  </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: "but apparently it only works when I check the label, when I check again just show standard display" I cannot reproduce that problem. In your demo when I click the black box, it always rotates and then switches colors on the next rotate. Could you describe what your desired behaviour is when the box is clicked?

Comment: @Juliette the switching colors that you see, it is the div showing you'rs first state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made few tweaks to the code. Kindly check whether it satisfies your requirement.

Your input type contains the id and class of the same name. You mentioned .ativar-dark in the CSS but when I changed it to #ativar-dark it was working fine which is bit strange because id and class can have the same name.

```css
.ativar-dark{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
}

#sky {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rotator {
  position: relative;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 3rem;
  transform: rotate(0deg); /*enter 0 deg in order to return back to the original position when unchecked */
  transition: all ease 2s; /* This will make sure it provides the animated effect when unchecked */

}

label{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rotator:before, #rotator:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: inherit;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

#rotator:before {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 2rem; /* Move the position of circle to center position */
  left: -1.25rem;
}

#rotator:after {
  background-color: White;
  bottom: 2rem; /* Move the position of circle to center position */
  right: -1.25rem;
}

#ativar-dark:checked ~ .container div{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all ease 2s;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ativar-dark" class="ativar-dark">
<div class="container" id="sky">
  <label for="ativar-dark"> 
  <div id="rotator">
    
  </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: bullseye, thank you so much, i think that i dont need to say that i'm newby in web dev, and i'm kind of try{}catch{} learner and your's changes explain a lot of thinghs. Fellow, you made my day.

Comment: @Half I am glad to hear that. It would be nice if you could accept this as an answer to your question. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle two classes using javascript to achieve the rotation on the click of the rotation element. Start with one present in the HTML element, then toggle them on click.

```js
let circle = document.getElementById('rotator')
circle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('rotate')
  e.target.classList.toggle('reverse')
})
```

```css
.ativar-dark {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

#sky {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rotator {
  position: relative;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  transform: rotate(-45);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 3rem;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rotator:before,
#rotator:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: inherit;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

#rotator:before {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: -.25rem;
  left: -.25rem;
}

#rotator:after {
  background-color: White;
  bottom: -.25rem;
  right: -.25rem;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all ease 2s;
}

.reverse {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all ease 2s;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ativar-dark" class="ativar-dark">
<div class="container" id="sky">
  <label for="ativar-dark"> 
    <div id="rotator" class="reverse">

    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate that you come up with a solution, thank you for that, but i'm try to do "css only", thank you again.